# How to ignore a command

Tags: macros

I am using the command `\phantom` in the document, and would like to add some command to the top of the document that will cancel the effect of `\phantom` (so that it would be easy for me to undo that later if I decide). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `\let\phantom\relax` might work if you want the argument of `\phantom` to print out in the normal way (except that it will be in its own group).   If you wanted the argument to have no effect at all, you might try `\def\phantom#1{}`.

Comment: The easiest way would probably to not use `\phantom` in the first place, but to define your own command `\newcommand{\imundecided}[1]{\phantom{#1}}`. That way you later can simply exchange the definition of your new command to show the content without breaking anything in `\phantom`.

Comment: I would use something like `\def\phantom#1{{\color{red} #1}}` or something similar (maybe a tight red box around it?) to show where the commands are... but yes, @Timm suggestion is better, to avoid messing with possible hidden usage of `\phantom` by some internal function.

Comment: @Rmano The main problem is that `\phantom` is a kernel command and redefining it can cause havoc.

Comment: I agree with Timm and egreg, if you redefine `\phantom` what could it happen if you actually need a `\phantom`, for example in a math formula? It's much better to create a new command, as Timm said, `\newcommand{\iamundecided}[1]{\phantom{#1}}` and redefine it with `\newcommand{\iamundecided}[1]{#1}` if you change your mind.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to redefine `\phantom`, if you do it would be

```
\renewcommand\phantom[1]{#1}
```

for example but this will break the `multicol` package (among other packages) unless you want a visible `p` inserting at the end of the text.

Instead use

```
\newcommand\myphantom[1]{\phantom{#1}}
%\newcommand\myphantom[1]{#1}
```

and then use `\myphantom{abc}` in your code, switch the commented line or simply rewrite the first line.

Comment: @Timm thanks the `5` should have been `%` of course but your edit is fine.

Comment: I initially only wanted to edit the 5, but the system forced me to edit at least 6 characters, so I decided to (hopefully) improve the answer further.